# Does "unbounded" necessarily imply "goes to infinity"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, closed-map

I am trying to understand this question [How does continuity implies closeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963024/how-does-continuity-implies-closeness) by this guy @Logan.  In the proof linked to in the question (linked again here) [Theorem 1.2](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/notes/nlp/unoc.pdf), it states

> Suppose to the contrary that there is an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the set $S=\{x|f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is unbounded.  Then there must exist a sequence $\{x^v\} \subset S$ with $||x^v||\rightarrow\infty$.

I do not understand why this sequence must necessarilly go to $\infty$ just because it is unbounded.  Do all unbounded sequences go to $\infty$?

From what I've seen (e.g. [Unbounded sequence diverging to $\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465378/unbounded-sequence-diverging-to-infty)) that is not true.  So why is it saying that in this proof?

Related: [How does continuity implies closeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963024/how-does-continuity-implies-closeness)

Comment: No, he's saying there must be a subsequence that goes to infinity.  Think about $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\dots$

Comment: Who's "he" in this context?

Comment: Take any unbounded sequence in $S$ and consider the sequence of the norms. You obtain a sequence **of positive reals** that is unbounded, so it has a **subsequence** diverging to $+\infty$. Then you can just consider this subsequence only.

Comment: @Candic3 "this guy" you are quoting.

Comment: That's not Logan.  if you follow the link, it's a proof given by a class at a university.

Comment: $$f(n)=\begin{cases}0&n\text{ even}\\n&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ is unbounded but doesn't go to infinity.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I guess there are two things contributing to my confusion here.  1) When the proof says "Then there must exist a *sequence*" I guess it should be called "subsequence" instead, right?   2) Also, ${x^v} \subset S $ with $ ||x^v|| \rightarrow \infty$ must be the notation for "subsequence", which I did not know.  I thought it was the notation for "sequence" not subsequence.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

A "subsequence" implies that you have a sequence in the first place. An unbounded sequence has a divergent subsequence. Here we have an unbounded set. What the proof is doing is *choosing* a sequence that is divergent. One way of doing this is as follows:

"Unbounded" means that there is no bound, i.e. there is no $R$ so that $\lVert x\rVert < R$ for every $x \in S$.

Let $R_i$ be an increasing sequence of positive real numbers that diverges to $\infty$ ( $(1,2,3,\dotsc)$ will work). Then $R_1$ is not a bound for $S$, so there is $x_1 \in S$ with $\lVert x_1 \rVert > R_1$. Similarly, $R_2$ is not a bound for $S$, so there is $x_2 \in S$ with $\lVert x_2 \rVert > R_2$. Continue doing this for each $i$, and you end up with a sequence $x_i$ with $\lVert x_i \rVert \to \infty$, as required.

Comment: okay,  i think i've finally understand.  Since "every unbounded sequence contains a subsequence which diverges to infinity", then we are allowed to make this claim:  "If $S=\{x\|f(x) \le \alpha \}$, is unbounded, then $\exists \{x^v\} \in S$" such that $\{x^v\} \rightarrow \infty$ and hence since the norm is always positive then we can say   $\{||x^v\||\} \rightarrow \infty$, for this paricular subsequence, too.  right? *Source*:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523985/prove-that-every-unbounded-sequence-contains-a-monotone-subsequence-that-diverge

Comment: $x^{\nu} \to \infty$ mean $\lVert x^{\nu} \rVert \to \infty$ (how else could you define it?). The point I'm trying to make in the answer is that there is no need to start with a sequence that you only know is unbounded: you can construct one that you *know* diverges in the first place.